# 2 or multiple Worksheet_Change different Error Handling / Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function, worksheet

I am trying to have 2 Worksheet_Change Events on one worksheet that are being triggered seperatly.

For example if I write in "C3" a Number a vlookup is either giving back a name or jumping to OnError GoTo NoSupplier, if i write in "C9" an other vlookup is either giving back a name or jumping to On Error GoTo NoCOMS.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim suppname As String
Dim COMS As String

If Target.Address(0, 0) = "C3" Then
    If Target <> "" Then
        On Error GoTo NoSupp
        suppname = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, Workbooks("Articlepassport.xlsm") _
        .Sheets("Suppliernames").Range("A2:B1000"), 2, False)
        Range("C5") = suppname
    Else
        Range("C5") = ""
    End If
Exit Sub

NoSupp: Range("C5") = "Supplier Data not maintained!"
End If

If Target.Address(0, 0) = "C9" Then
    If Target <> "" Then
        On Error GoTo NoCOMS
        COMS = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, Workbooks("Articlepassport.xlsm") _
        .Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("A2:B11000"), 2, False)
        Range("C11") = COMS
    Else
        Range("C11") = ""
    End If
Exit Sub

NoCOMS: Range("C11") = "COMS does not exist!"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `Application.EnableEvents = False` so the Sub won't be triggerred multiple times. Before leaving the `Sub`, you need to restore the settings to the original value with `Application.EnableEvents = True`.

Note: I've removed your orginal Error Handlers, and I've added a way to deal with the `VLookup` errors, by adding `If IsError(suppname) Then` and `If IsError(COMS) Then`.

**Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim suppname As Variant
Dim COMS As Variant

Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Range("C3"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then

        suppname = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, Workbooks("Articlepassport.xlsm") _
        .Sheets("SupplierNames").Range("B2:H1000"), 4, False)
        If IsError(suppname) Then
            Range("C5").Value = "Supplier Data not maintained!"
        Else
            Range("C5").Value = suppname
        End If
    Else
       Range("C5") = ""
    End If
End If

If Not Intersect(Range("C9"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then

        COMS = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, Workbooks("Articlepassport.xlsm") _
        .Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("A2:B11000"), 2, False)
        If IsError(COMS) Then
            Range("C11").Value = "COMS does not exist!"
        Else
            Range("C11").Value = ""
        End If
    Else
        Range("C11").Value = ""
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True ' reset settings when leaving this Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for, but initally I thought `If Not Intersect` would not work with my approache since it would need a range of 2 cells or more

Answer (score 0):

Edited function; generally for worksheet change events, you should deactivate events (and screenupdating) then allow re-activating on error, or sub completion.

Rewritten function (untested)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

On Error GoTo ExitSub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Select Case Target
        Case Range("C3")
            If Target.Value = "" Then
                Range("C5") = ""
                GoTo ExitSub
            End If
            Dim SupplierName As String
            On Error Resume Next
            SupplierName = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, Workbooks("Articlepassport.xlsm") _
                .Sheets("SupplierNames").Range("B2:H1000"), 4, False)
            On Error GoTo ExitSub
            Range("C5").Value = IIf(SupplierName <> "", SupplierName, "Supplier data not maintained!")
        Case Range("C9")
            If Target.Value = "" Then
                Range("C11") = ""
                GoTo ExitSub
            End If
            Dim COMS As String
            On Error Resume Next
            COMS = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, Workbooks("Articlepassport.xlsm") _
                .Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("A2:B11000"), 2, False)
            On Error GoTo ExitSub
            Range("C11").Value = IIf(COMS <> "", COMS, "COMS does not exist!")
        Case Else
    End Select

ExitSub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Seriously ? you are advising the PO **not**  to deal with his errors , but to use `On Error Resume Next` ?

Comment: Why do you need to deal with an error here? Resume is used for a single call to a vlookup. You only want to know if the value is found or not, then act on that. If the call errors; then SupplierName/COMS = "" and that is caught in the next line

Comment: This doesn't quite do what I would like it to do, since the error handler in "C5" is triggered even when I delete the value in "C3". But I already found the mistake in my own code since I used a wrong relation which let the whole code to run in the errors. I will edit my Question for whoever might need to use my example.

Comment: Oh yes, I failed to notice that part... Updated for completeness